# is there a way to use the same webdriver object for multiple java classes when running within a testng suite?

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, testng

is there a way to use the same webdriver object for multiple tests/classes when run within a testng suite? What I mean is to start the WebDriver instance with one class, but continue using it over subsequent classes/tests in the suite?

The problem I am facing is that 10 differect classes have this statement:

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

and it open 10 different instances even after I restrict TestNG with parallel mode set a s false. It really sucks up my system memory.

I wat a solution to use same WebDriver and run different classes over without having to multiple browser and Webdriver insntances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put all your classes in a `<test>` tag and initialize the driver in a `@BeforeTest` method which you store in the base class so that all your test methods can access it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "@BeforeClass" ?

Comment: It depends when you want to initialize your web driver. If it's only once before all the classes run, then \@BeforeTest. If it's before each class, then \@BeforeClass.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar kind of issue. I have multiple java files which perform some test case operations. I am using PhantomJSDriver class so as to achieve headless browser testing. I have one class from whose static block I am getting initialized with my PhantomJSDriver class's object. I run several test case java files from one shell script. When my first test case runs,I am performing login first, but this same login doesn't works when I run the second test case file, and it again asks for login. Might be because the PhantomJSDriver object gets destroyed on finish of first java file.Help

Comment: Hello there, can anyone please suggest me how we can implement the above solution given by @CedricBeust. I am facing the same issue, where I am running several java files using a shell script and the only thing I need is to use same PhantomJSDriver object across ALL test case files, so that one single browser instance can handle all of the test cases. How can I do that ? PLEASE PLEASE Help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is in java but in c# you just instantiate the webdriver as a field

```
private WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

then just reference driver from that point on out

```
driver.findElements(By.TagName('h1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

[ISFW](http://seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.html#testing-frameworks) provides nice way to handle it. It will creates new instance if required otherwise utilize the same one. However you don't require to write code for setup and teardown. You need to set browser string in property file and it will manage for RC or webdriver for given browser string.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this as following:

1: created a startup class

```
public class Start {
    public static WebDriver wd;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void Setup() {
    System.setProperty "webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\chromedriver.exe");
    wd = new ChromeDriver();
    wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wd.manage().window().maximize();
    wd.get("URL");}
    }
```

2: reference the static driver instance in other classes by its class qualifier as

```
public void VerifyTitle() {
    Assert.assertEquals(Start.wd.getTitle(), "Title", "Incorrect Title");}
```

3: add the class and the setup method in testing.xml file as

```
<suite name="QA">
   <test name="1Class">
      <classes>
         <class name="just.Start">
            <methods>
               <include name="Setup"></include>
            </methods>
         </class>
         <class name="just.LoginPage">
            <methods>
               <include name="VerifyTitle"></include>
            </methods>
         </class>
         <class name="just.HomePage">
            <methods>
               <include name="VerifyUserLogin"></include>           
            </methods>
         </class>

      </classes>
    </test> 
  </suite>
```

I have implemented this in Java.

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to run the test cases in parallel then you would need to have a separate webdriver instance associated with each test. You can't share the instance across tests in a multithreaded environment.

As for abstracting the initialization of the webdriver instance, there are several ways out there. You could perhaps write a base TestCase class that would build the webdriver instance. Each of your test cases will then extend TestCase class, along those lines.

In TestNG you can control the thread count by specifying the parameter `-threadcount` in testng.xml. Check out the documentation [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html). If you are launching TestNG programatically then you can use `setThreadCount` method. Check Java docs [here](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNG.html).

Answer (score -1):

Under one package:

Test1.java -> Have @BeforeTest and @AfterTest to launch the browser and close the browser respectively.

Eg:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void open_browser()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void close_browser()
    {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Login.java

public class Login {

```
@Test
public static void logintest{

    Webelement ele1 = Test1.driver.findElement(...);
}
```

}

In your XML file:

```
<test name = "MyTest">
    <classes>
        <class name = "Test1"></class>
        <class name = "Login"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

This will make use of driver instance created in the Test1 file.

Hope it helps !! :)

Answer (score -1):

The Best Way to handle this is:

Have one BaseClass where you just initate the Browser.

```
public class BaseClass
{
  public static Webdriver driver;
@BeforeSuite
  public void Launch_Browser()
  {
  webDriver Driver= new FirefoxDriver();
  }
}
```

Then Extend the BaseClass to your all other classes -by usings extend

```
public class Class1 extends BaseClass
 {
   @Test
    public void TC1()
      {
          //PASS
        }   

 }
```

and so on. The important thing is you should declare webdriver driver as public static in BaseClass.