# Login only once for several test cases - Selenium, JUnit

Tags: selenium, junit4

I am using Selenium 2.X with JUnit 4.X for automation testing. There are several test cases in the test class. However the for each test cases the a new session is created.

That is for each test case,
 
a new browser window is opened,
 
login mechanism is carried out,
 
generic steps gets executed,
 
test steps gets executed,
 
the browser get closed.

Is there any possibility for the below mentioned?

a new browser window is opened,
 
login mechanism is carried out,
 
generic steps gets executed,

The above steps are carried out only once

all test steps (methods with @Test) gets executed,

Finally the browser gets closed?

PS: I do not want to club all the test case in a single one?

Thanks,

Comment: This post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908254/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-same-webdriver-object-for-multiple-java-classes-when-r might be useful

Answer (score 0):

With every new browser session, Selenium creates a new instance of the browser test profile - so re-invoking will cause you to start afresh.

You requirement, though, appears to be more organizational.

Try working with [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html). It enables the creation of test suites, which can be executed via a `testng.xml`. You should be able to script tests in different classes and then call them sequentially, without having to necessarily re-invoke the browser